# React JSX Components `url` Returning Undefined

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, jsx

I am currently attempting to learn React (JSX), and follow the first half of the https://reactjs.net/tutorials/aspnetcore.html React for aspnet tutorial.

I have created an Endpoint `/comments` that provides a simple list of static comments as json, as outlined in the tutorial. The endpoint is accessible and does indeed return the data as intended (verified through swagger and browser), however when calling `render` with `<CommentBox url="/comments" />` the `this.props.data` object is undefined, at least according to the out of the `console.log` in my browser; React snippet below.

Naturally the Component will not render, however, using a locally defined static `const data = [{...}, {...}, {...}]` and passing this into the component works fine`

This seems like absolute childs-play, however I am going crazy trying to figure it out. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <CommentBox url="/comments" />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);

class CommentBox extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.data)
        return (
            <div className="commentBox">
                <h1>Comments</h1>
                <CommentList data={this.props.data} />
                <CommentForm />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the `data` property in your component? What happened to `url`?

Comment: I was asking myself this also, there is no mention of changing the object being referenced in the CommentBox component in the tutorial. However, you're correct `this.props.data` likely doesn't exist anymore for that function.

However I don't know how to access the data being fetched by `url` in the component.

Comment: Every attribute you set in the markup will map to a corresponding property in the `props` object in your component. Since you set `<CommentBox url="..." />`, you would access that value within your `CommentBox` component as `this.props.url`. No `data` attribute was set so the `this.props.data` property remains `undefined`.

Comment: This likely also means that the data is likely not implicitly fetched and passed through by setting the `url` property for the `CommentBox` component correct?

Comment: Right, nor should it. It's no different than passing a parameter into a constructor of a class. You set a value upon construction, that same value is available in the component through the corresponding property in the `props` object.

Comment: Fair point :). It's odd then that the reactjs.net tutorial implies that using the `url` parameter implicitly fetches the data when being passed into the component.

But hey, it is easy enough for me to handle the fetching of the data myself :).

Thank you.

Comment: You might not have gotten far enough into the tutorial to see how it gets used. See the section under "Updating state" where it has added code for the `componentWillMount()` hook. It's actually doing an ajax call when it's setting up the component.